# When using signInWithCustomToken in Firebase how do you set the validated state of the new user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using 3rd party auth with Firebase...everything works great - user created etc.

But my user is not validated (because created by token) and my existing code checks for validation.

When creating a user via 3rd party, how do you set validation? Or otherwise deal with this situation?

Comment: Do you mean: email verified? You are already using Admin SDK to generate the custom token, you can create or update the user's account with the field "emailverified" as true: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: Thanks for looking...

I'm using php, which doesn't offer the admin feature to update the emailVerified parameter. Why Firebase would create a user via customauth and make them NOT verified is a mystery to me...

I'm now trying to get Node.js going, but I have zero experience and I want to update one freakin' field...

Comment: I see. You are correct, as far as I know, there isn't a public REST endpoint to create or update accounts, similar to the one used for creating the custom token. My first guess could be that Firebase creates the account with the minimal access and lets the developer modify any required information if needed. Could you clarify on why emailVerified is required if you are using custom authentication an not email & password?

Comment: This is the part that doesn't make any sense to me: if you use customAuth you are, by definition, depending on another authority for identity. But Firebase makes the new user require email validation.

Which seems like a mistake to me.

With a little help from Firebase support I realized that my check for "is user validated" could have some additional logic...my code knows if the user has come from oauth, and so I just bypass the email validation requirement in my code in that case.

Make sense?

The author of the PHP admin library for Firebase just added emailVerified as an option.